# Is there any way to get the page title and http status code from just domain?

Tags: python, http, subdomain

I am trying to make a script that will get the page title, HTTP status code and content-length from domain. after searching in the web. I only found way to do that by full url. I don't have the full url. I have the domain (a subdomain to be exact) and its ip.

How do I get the page title, HTTP status code and content-length from just the domain using python?

Comment: If you have IP address (numeric or otherwise), you can always construct an URL by supplying protocol (`http` or `https`) and path: `http://example.com` identifies the page at `/` on `example.com`.

Comment: @Amadan An IP **address** can not be something else than numeric... If it not numeric, such as `example.com` it is a name, not an IP address!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You are right, I misspoke. It makes little difference here, though.

Comment: @Amadan How do i do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been playing around with it a bit and have found an awesome tool that can get full url from just the domain. It can also get HTTP status, content-length, ip, title etc.
It is called httpx
https://github.com/projectdiscovery/httpx

Answer (score 0):

To construct a URL, use:

```
domain = 'example.com'
if domain.count('.') == 1:
    url = f'https://www.{domain}'
else:
    url = f'https://{domain}'
```

Comment: Thanks man! I used Try and except to determine if it will be http or https.